# Is there a way to not destruct child of dialog for wxwidget

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a dialog which is populated with auinotebook tab panels but every time I close the dialog it will destruct my tabs, however I want to know if there is a way I can keep the tabs in memory for the next time I create the dialog fresh. I don't want to cache dialog, but just the tabs.

I create dialog on the stack so it will call destructor when I close it, but i create tabs on the heap and have a map to keep the address of tabs, but they are allocated since the children of dialog are destroyed.

Any ideas if this is even possible? If so any hints how to do it?

Comment: Instead of closing the dialog,  simply hide it.  Then show it again when needed.

Comment: @ravenspoint i would rather have dialog destructed and then constructed again, but just memorizing the tabs, so it will be faster to embed that in a dialog.

Comment: If the problem is that the tabs take too long to construct, then IMHO instead of trying to outsmart the GUI framework, you should find out what is taking the time in your code and optimize or cache that,

Comment: @ravenspoint what about using wxPersistenceManager?

Comment: I believe that you are tackling the problem from the wrong end.  You need to find out what is causing the construction of your tabs to be unacceptably slow.  When you know that, you can solve the real problem, either by optimizing the construction code, or caching the results.  For example: you may need a bitmap, which you can construct once and store in memory.

Comment: @ravenspoint its too big of a task to optimize it. Its also very large data.

Comment: @ravenspoint using     
using wxPersistenceMager to save the panels in the memory? Is this possible?

Comment: "(tab construction is )  too big of a task to optimize"  There are serious problems with your design. You must focus on your problems and quit trying to use the GUI framework to rescue you from your design error(s).  Close this question and ask a new one on how to sort out your real problem.

Comment: @ravenspoint its not the tab but controls in tab panel which are populated with big selection of data

Comment: Then do not populate the controls until they are activated - just show them.  Or, as I suggested yesterday, cache the data, rather than calculating it anew each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't keep children of a window alive when the window itself is destroyed, so you either need to keep the entire dialog around (typically by hiding it, as advised by @ravenspoint), or reparent the tabs under some other window and then reparent them back under the dialog when it's recreated. But it's not really clear what advantage does the latter have compared to the former, so I'd just keep the dialog.

Another useful trick which could be relevant is to construct the tabs on demand only, i.e. initially construct only the first tab and create the other ones only when they're about to be shown. IME creating a single tab should be fast enough even if creating all of them takes too long.

Comment: Thanks for a feedback. I have tabs create on demand. What about using wxPersistenceManager?

Comment: Err, what about it? It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question.

Comment: using wxPersistenceMager to save the panels in the memory? Is this possible?

Comment: `wxPersistenceManager` doesn't do what you seem to think it does, I advise you to read the [documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/overview_persistence.html).